# LIKE SQL with parameters throwing Invalid Parameter Number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to use a "LIKE" in the SQL, basically to see if a player is in a team already. Here's the code I have:

```
    $checkifonlytwo = "SELECT * FROM sg_turn_teams WHERE joinid = :joinid AND players LIKE '%:ownerid,%'";
    $paramstwo = array(
        ":joinid" => $joinid,
        ":ownerid" => $_SESSION['user']['id']
    );
    try{
    $stmttwo = $db->prepare($checkifonlytwo);
    $resulttwo = $stmttwo->execute($paramstwo);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        die("Failed to run query #2: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
```

Also as you can see I want it to be `LIKE '%1,%'` for example, so the comma at the end too.

My table structure looks like this.
[image: table structure]

EDIT, the players is going to be like "1,2,3" without the names because the users are able to change their name. The picture is with names, but it's supposed to be 1,2,3

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing integer foreign keys in a string list.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do you mean? I do so because it's the IDs of the users, but there can be several so I need a list of them, like "1,2,3,4"

Comment: What does your table structure look like ?

Comment: echo     $checkifonlytw first and paste the same in sql and check whether data exist on same scenario??

Comment: you're going about it the wrong way with the comma in there `ownerid,`. What you need to do is implode on the array and use `IN()`, far as I can tell.

Comment: @PRANAV How would I go about echoing it with the parameters? I've actually tried echoing a duplicate string that used for example `LIKE '%".$_SESSION['user']['id'].",%'` and that looked perfect.

Comment: @Maximus2012 My table structure looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Ou71LBa.png)

Comment: I think you're trying to make it way more complicated than it needs to be. It'd be helpful if you could post your table structure along with some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Please update the question to include that information rather than adding a comment that points to an external link.

Comment: if you only have the one id, use a regular `WHERE id = :ownerid` *n'est-ce pas?*  Why use LIKE? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Because I'm trying to look up if the person is in a team rather than owning one. If he is in the "players" column. I've posted sample data in the question.

Comment: ok, my mistake. Again, see my first comment above. That's what you need to do. We need to know where those strings are coming from though and if the session was started.

Comment: You might want to use association tables rather than storing the information the way you are storing it.

Comment: Alright thanks guys. I guess I thought this would work but I'll just make another table for players. If any of you want to leave that as an answer I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Comment: @Maximus2012 perhaps bang out an example for him. Fame and fortune will shortly follow :)

Comment: @Drew I found a few that might be duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100434/php-pdo-select-array-within-in and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814466/php-pdo-mysql-in it's anybody's game. I'd hate to be the one having to justify code as examples and to get it to work with their present code. I think a wiki would be more the thing to do here.

Comment: Thank @Fred-ii- posted duplicate close

Comment: The moral of the story is it is treated like a `concat` because an `IN` with csv can't be bound

Comment: @Drew I posted a wiki. Anyone can modify/add to it.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I posted a wiki. You're welcome to add to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Foreword.* I decided to make this a community wiki. I did not want to gain anything from this, except for the OP and others visiting the question.

As I said in comments, you're going about it the wrong way with the comma in there `ownerid,`.

What you need to do is [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the array and using [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151295/

```
$e = 0;

while($e<$num1){
$units = 0;
$r = 0;
$SO_Line_Item=mysql_result($result1,$e,"SO_Line_Item");

    foreach ($Boxes[$e] as $a => $b)  
    {

        $zzz[] = $Boxes[$e][$r];

$ce = count($Boxes[$e]);        

    $r++; 
    }
//end inner foreach

$products = implode(',', array_fill(0,$ce, '?'));

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.1.197 ;dbname=Tracking', $dbuser,$dbpass);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Box_Num,Timestamp,E3_SN,Assy_Status FROM Current_Box WHERE Box_Num IN( $products )");
$stmt->execute($zzz);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
unset($zzz);
$e++;
}
```

and from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2814703/

```
$ids = array(2, 4, 6, 8);

// prepare a string that contains ":id_0,..,:id_n" and include it in the SQL
$plist = ':id_'.implode(',:id_', array_keys($ids));
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someId IN ($plist)";
// prepare & execute the actual statement
$parms = array_combine(explode(",", $plist), $ids);
$stmt  = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$rows  = $stmt->execute($parms);
```

From comments:

> *"You might want to use association tables rather than storing the information the way you are storing it. – Maximus2012"*

**As mentioned in the comments, some questions/answers from SO that demonstrate the concept of Association tables along with composite primary keys:**

[Mysql : Association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421087/mysql-association-table)

[How to use an MySQL association table to return categories not currently assigned to an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986493/how-to-use-an-mysql-association-table-to-return-categories-not-currently-assigne)

If OP decides to go with this structure then the queries would need to be changed to make use of `LEFT JOIN` and/or use a sub-query with `IN` clause. There are plenty of examples of both on SO. One that I could find with a simple search (please ignore the slow query part and look at the examples to demonstrate the concept):

[MySQL - SELECT WHERE field IN (subquery) - Extremely slow why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why)